# How to remove the Custom Fields menu?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I use the `Advanced Custom Fields` plugin, but I want to remove the menu `Custom Fields`.

[image]

The code is the following:

```
add_filter('admin_menu', function() {
    remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=acf');
});
```

But it doesn't work. Is there something wrong, or does anyone know a method to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you plz add this function in your theme functions.php file

```
function remove_menus(){
   remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=acf' ); //Remove Post Type ACF
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'remove_menus' );
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the logic I use to restrict the menu by user name.

```
/**
 * Hide ACF admin menu from non-approved users.
 */
function wpgood_restrict_acf_menu( $show ) {
    // array of user names that are allowed to see ACF menu
    $allowedUsers = array(
        'YOUR USER NAME HERE',
        'ANOTHER APPROVED USER NAME HERE'
    );
    // get the current user
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $current_user_name = $current_user->user_login;
    if (in_array($current_user_name, $allowedUsers)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
add_filter('acf/settings/show_admin', 'wpgood_restrict_acf_menu');
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my function for hiding the Custom Fields menu. It allows you to specify userids that should still be able to see the menu.

```
// hide ACF menus for all users except those specified
function show_hide_acf_menu( $show ) {

    // array of user IDs that are allowed to see ACF menu
    $allowedUsers = array(1);

    // get the current user's ID
    $userID = get_current_user_id();

    if (in_array($userID, $allowedUsers)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
add_filter('acf/settings/show_admin', 'show_hide_acf_menu');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it seems that it doesn't work. Is there something I need to  pay attention to?

Comment: Where are you placing the code? If you're using this code unmodified and you're logging in with userid 1 you will still see the Custom Fields menu.

Comment: functions.php，
`add_filter('acf/settings/show_admin', function() { return false; });`

Comment: copy the entire code block I provided into your functions.php

Comment: :( I can confirm this is working in my installation. Try replacing `array(1)` with `array()`. You may be logged in with the user that has the ID 1.

Comment: Sincerely thank you, but it still doesn't work. It may be something wrong with my PC.

Answer (score 2):

ACF has a filter for this, and you can use the WP '__return_false' function without the need for additional functions to be defined.

```
add_filter('acf/settings/show_admin', '__return_false');
```

---

References:

[ACF Documentation: acf/settings](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-settings/#settings)

[WP Documentation: __return_false](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__return_false/)

Answer (score 0):

Mukesh Panchal his answers is not working anymore.
They renamed is to:

```
remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=acf-field-group' )
```

That will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

There's a easy way to do that. You can hide the ACF menu for specific environment, setting a CONST in your wp-config.php.

Put this inside your function.php:

```
/*
* Hide acf from the wp=admin area.
*/
function awesome_acf_hide_acf_admin() {
    if (SHOW_ACF == 1) return true;
    return false;
}
add_filter('acf/settings/show_admin', 'awesome_acf_hide_acf_admin');
```

And define this CONST in your wp-config.php:

```
define( 'SHOW_ACF', true );
```

So you can change the value of this CONST if you want to hide the acf menu in your live site for example:

```
define( 'SHOW_ACF', false );
```

I hope it helps!